# IDA - Searching for a pushed value

Tags: ida

How do I search for a pushed value in IDA?

I have a value that is pushed into a certain function.

I want to search for it like:

```
push 420
```

How do I that?

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure you have closed all remaining search result windows. Such windows are titled with "Occurences of: ...". This is necessary to get the right window.
2. Hit "Alt+t" to open a new text search window.
3. In the search field, enter '`push    420`' without the '.
   **NB**: You have to get the number of spaces right. I got them like this: I searched for "push" only at first. Then I right clicked on the result, copied it and inserted it into my new search. This gives you the right number of spaces.
4. Make sure you have selected "Find all occurences". Make sure you have not selected any Parameters (e.g. "Regular expression", ...)
5. Hit OK